# Nth-child expression to remove margin-bottom doesn't work in responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors

What I wish to do is create an nth-child expression to remove the margin-bottom of on the last row when in desktop view and just remove margin-bottom of last item in responsive view, here an example or you can check **[live demo here](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/jEMGdj/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Test goes here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- end wrapper -->
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    border: 1px solid  #DFDFDF;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

So I try below code:

```
.col-md-3:nth-last-child(-n+4) .box {
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It works perfectly in large view, but when display in responsive view it doesn't work. Hope anyone can give me advice.

Comment: A responsive view can be large and small. Do you want to make it work for mobile view?

Comment: Yes, that I mean sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `@media` queries to do this.

For selecting normally use `.col-md-3:not(:nth-last-child(-n+4)) .box` selector to set the `margin-bottom`. It will select all but last four `div`s.

For responsive view, use `.col-md-3:not(:last-of-type) .box` selector to set the `margin-bottom`. This will select all but the last `div`.

The `width` of `.col-md-3` was found using JavaScript, which is `991px`.

<kbd>**Working demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/pvEWXo)**</kbd>

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid  #DFDFDF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.col-md-3:not(:nth-last-child(-n+4)) .box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
  .col-md-3:not(:last-of-type) .box {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Test goes here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  <!-- end wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. Can I add you more question, in case I use another column (such as: col-md-2, col-md-4,...) How can I apply this code, I think js would be better.

Comment: @user3127538 - It is possible using CSS alone. What you could do is, when the content snaps the `width` while resizing the `window`'s width, get the `width` of the `window` using `alert(window.innerWidth)` and add `@media` queries for that as well, just like my answer.

Comment: @TheHung - No Worries! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `margin-bottom` just to the last item, don't use `-n+4` in your `nth-last-child`, use just `1`.

Comment: It just remove margin-bottom of one item of last row when in desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean though.
You could try using percentages. They re-adjust to different sizes when adjusting your browser, or if your on a tablet/phone percentages can work better. Exact pixels take up the exact space, as percentages take up a percentage of the page.

Example:

```
.box{
    padding: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the max width of your mobile view but you can play with this.
Use the below CSS:

```
.box{
  border: 1px solid  #DFDFDF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
  .col-md-3:nth-last-child(1) .box {
     margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried in your CodePen and it worked. Just copy the above CSS and try.